# What is the most efficient MySQL data type for long bitstrings?

Tags: mysql, performance, types, bit-manipulation, sqldatatypes

I have a need to store into a MySQL table lengthy bit-strings which could be as long as 32768 bits. This data need will not need to be indexed or full-text searched at any time. If I have read correctly, this size should be well within both my max_packet_size as well as the row-size limit @ 65k.

Ideally I would like to store the strings (and INSERT them) in 0b format, but this is not a requirement...anything that will give me essentially 1:1 data/size on disk would be great.

BLOBs do not seem to do the job well enough, as a string comprised of only ones and zeroes ('010101010101') is seen no different than normal text and costs me L bytes + 2. BIT() would be perfect, but is limited only to 64 bits max length.

Though much of the data (90%+) would be sufficiently represented within an unsigned Bigint, the remaining 10% of rows entice me to find a more elegant solution than splitting them up logically (i.e., searching a secondary table if not found in the first, secondary table using BLOBs for remaining 10% rows, etc.).

An added bonus would be any type that permits bitwise operations, but if not, this is just as easily done outside the MySQL server.

What is the most efficient data type for this purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say it mainly depends on your access pattern. If you can afford to read/write the whole bitstring at each access, then a varbinary(4096) will work fine and be quite compact (only 2 bytes of overhead for the whole field). In this model, one bit on application side is really represented by one bit in the data storage, and it is up to the client application to interpret it as a bitstring (performing bitwise operations, etc ...)

If you want to optimize a bit more, you can imagine a table with a bigint and a varbinary(4096):

```
create table dummy (
   dummykey int not null,
   bit1 bigint null,
   bit2 varbinary(4096) null,
   primary key(dummykey)
);
```

Only one of the two fields is not null for a given record. If bit1 is not null, then it can store 64 bits. For larger bitstrings, bit1 is null, and bit2 is used instead. The client application has to be smart enough to handle all bitwise operations (paying special attention to signed/unsigned issues with bit1).

Comment: I've looked into varbinary as well, but according to [storage requirements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html), doesn't varbinary(32768) still cost me 1 byte per bit of my bitstring...or should I come to expect this is as optimized as it can be for strings that long?

Comment: Nevermind, I understand your suggestion: each bit in varbinary(4096) will instead be a character that bit-for-bit represents 8 characters of my string and I simply iterate through the varbinary string to determine these values and restore the final bit string.

This is definitely ideal since I am more than willing to trade computational time on the client for storage and access time on the server. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I guess the BLOB type is what you need. It can represent binary strings up to 2^16 **bytes** and has an overhead of 2 **bytes** per record (if L is the length in **bytes** of the value, L+2 **bytes** is its size on disk).

Then, if you really want to optimize, use two tables, one with BLOB and the other with TINYBLOB (strings up to 2^8 **bytes**, 1 **byte** overhead), then UNION them together in a VIEW or during SELECT.

If you want to optimize even more, use a third table with BIGINT (this will allow storing binary strings up to 58 **bits**, since the remaining 6 will be needed to store the length of the binary string).

Comment: One of the main reasons I was so pleased with the answer from @Didier is that it addressed my main concern of minimum disk storage use.  Using a BLOB or TINYBLOB to store binary strings still costs me 1 byte per bit, e.g., '01010101' costs me 8 bytes (8 bits per char) under these types.

Two or three tables unioned vs the BIGINT null, VARBINARY null does seem like it's veering away from the KISS principle, but thank you for your input.

Comment: @hexparrot can you please point out in the manual where it says what you're claiming? AFAIU, the MySQL manual says that storing 1 byte in a TINYBLOB will need 2 bytes on disk, not 8.

Comment: [Storage requirements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html) show that blob take "L + 2 bytes, where L < 2^16" where "L represents the actual length in bytes of a given string value."

Since your solution does not recommend the same bitwise parsing the accepted solution does, I can only assume you mean for my '10101010' string to be stored AS-IS, which would be 8 chars at 1 byte each.

Keep in mind this is strictly about the storage of the actual data, rather than the overt overhead that is, indeed, 2bytes per BLOB.

Comment: @hexparrot wait, why would you pass in your bitstring as a sequence of 0 and 1 ASCII chars? that's insane! you need to pass in (escaped) binary data, not a string like '010001001110'!

Comment: @hexparrot If I didn't mention explicitely the "bitwise parsing" is because it's obvious (note, in fact, that in the third phrase I'm talking about **58 bits**, i.e. a number of bits that's not multiple of 8)

Comment: I fail to see how 'bitwise parsing' is inferred at all by the fact BIGINT is represented by 58 bits simply because it is not a multiple of 8--what relevance is that? BIGINT is useful because it can already accurately represent a bitsring up to 58 chars WITHOUT parsing--parsing would be utterly pointless for such a string. Thus, you recommend bit-parsing on the data type that does NOT need it and recommend a more complicated schema with 3 tables bigint/tinyblob/blob, where varbinary will automatically size itself  appropriately for overhead if the data is < 255 bytes, and +2 bytes for over....

Comment: @hexparrot please explain WHY you need to pass the data as a sequence of '0' and '1' **ASCII chars**. the correct way to do that is by sending binary data!!! by doing it your way, you're moving 8 times the amount of data on the network!

Comment: In the original post, I asked for a means to be able to STORE in 0b format, in which bitstrings would be stored like 0b10101010.  As such, I was expecting a string of variable length up to 32768 to be sent within the query itself, which was transfer INEFFICIENT, but seeking BITWISE operation capability within the SQL server itself.  It has long been established SINCE THEN that this method would not be employed, since without a doubt, the most efficient means for me to move the data is by moving not '0' and '1' ASCII chars but instead the ASCII char representing 8 characters of the string.

Comment: While it would still be desirable for the SQL engine to do the bitwise operations for me, rather than transfer bit-compressed ASCII strings and do bit-parsing, it has become apparent there are no suitable means for me to do bitwise operations on all my strings larger than BIGINT.  In hopes to conclude this thread entirely, I must reiterate how your provided solution is an INFERIOR alternative to the accepted solution , though it is a SUPERIOR solution to what I initially thought of doing by deciding to send '0' and '1' as ASCII chars (which was never a transfer concern, but a storage one)